# wordpress bootstrap navigation navbar auto collapse, not in open state

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, navbar, wp-nav-walker

[image]I am developing a WordPress theme and for navbar using a navwalker code,
the problem is when I click on the menu button in mobile it's open and closed in a millisecond. It's working in localhost properly but not in the server.

Wordpress: 5.2
navwalker: custom WordPress nav walker class for Bootstrap 4 
Bootstrap: 4.3.1
URL of site: https://www.androidinterview.com/

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header has-header">
    <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light">
        <div class="site-branding navbar-brand">
            <?php
            the_custom_logo();
            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
                ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            else :
                ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            endif;
            $ehsdev_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $ehsdev_description || is_customize_preview() ) :
                ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $ehsdev_description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->


        <button class="navbar-toggler p-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs4navbar" aria-controls="bs4navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>

        <?php
        wp_nav_menu([
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_id'      => 'bs4navbar',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'menu_id'           => 'false',
            'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'fallback_cb'       => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new bs4Navwalker()
        ]);
        ?>
    </nav>

    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

function.php

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/bootstrap-wp-navwalker.php';

register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'ehsdev' ),
        ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found out that a plugin was loading Bootstrap 3 while I was also loading BootStrap 4.
Your case is the same.
I can see as in the image below you are loading BootStrap 4.3.1
[Sources on Chrome Web dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTi9j.png)

But there is another plugin loading BootStrap 3.3.4 see image below

[Sources with bootstrap 3.3.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaUYX.png)

In my case I just deleted the bootstrap from the plugin
Or you could use the same version of BootStrap and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use Bootstrap v3.3.4 css with Bootstrap v4.3.1 js?

Try changing either the css or the js file to compatible version?

Hope that helps

[image]

Comment: nope, i used v4.3.1 css of bootstrap, all files are latest and same. It's working in localhost.

Comment: How? I uploaded the same theme in different domain its working fine. I think its a problem of any plugin uploading old bootstrap. [checking what making issue] Thanks.

Comment: Yes maybe some old css is messing it up? Maybe remove that  yes :)